# Use FAKE to Tag a git branch after build

Tags: f#-fake

Is it possible to set up a Target that creates and pushes a git tag on a remote after the Build Target completes?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

I used the following which seems to work

```
Target "TagBuild" (fun _ ->
  open Fake.Git
  let versionNumber = "1.0.0.0"
  let repositoryRoot = "../"
  let branchName = Fake.Git.Information.getBranchName repositoryRoot
  trace ("Current GIT Branch: " + branchName)

  let tagName = ("build_" + versionNumber)
  trace ("Creating Tag: " + tagName)
  tag repositoryRoot tagName
  pushTag repositoryRoot  "origin" tagName)
```